# How do you set asterisk as the second footnote type with bigfoot

Tags: bigfoot

This is the code i have :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}

\begin{document}
    text one\footnote{set 1}
    text two\footnoteB{set 2}
\end{document}
```

but the second footnotes are alphabetic and i need * for any of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can renew the secondary footnotemark like the regular footnotemark:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{*}
\begin{document}
    text one\footnote{set 1}
    text two\footnoteB{set 2}
    text three\footnoteB{set 3}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> text one¹ text two* text three*